# plotting with different values per key and different color per key

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a list with 3 dictionaries each with multiple values.
I want to create a graph in which each key is a line in a different color (say r, g, b) formed by its  values. Also I want a legend for each line.

This is the code I started with:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(14,8)) 
plt.title('Grafico ripetizioni per linea')
plt.xlabel('numero caratteri')
plt.ylabel('ripetizioni per linea')
for k in dd.keys():
    plt.locator_params(axis='y', nbins=15)
    for v in dd.values():        
        plt.locator_params(axis='x', nbins=30)
        xs = range(0, len(v))
        ys = v
        plt.plot(xs, ys, label='chiave' + str(k))
plt.minorticks_on()
plt.margins(x=0)
plt.show()
```

I obtain a plot with the three lines with different colors, but 
don't know ho to specify color and label for each line.

Comment: You are using `k` for your plot labels, but when creating the plot you are iterating in a nested loop over `dd.values()` using the variable `v`. I think your label should be `label='chiave'+str(v)` (or something else, but definitely not with `k`, it's hard to tell without the data. But `k` is constant in your  `for v in dd.values()` loop)

Comment: Actually K is a variable looping the 3 keys and for each key v are the values plotted on the y-axis while the x-axis represent the lenght of a text. That's why there is a nested loop.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
 Calling `plt.legend` will give you the `label` for each key.

```
plt.figure(figsize=(14,8)) 
plt.title('Grafico ripetizioni per linea')
plt.xlabel('numero caratteri')
plt.ylabel('ripetizioni per linea')
for k in dd.keys():
    plt.locator_params(axis='y', nbins=15)
    for v in dd.values():        
        plt.locator_params(axis='x', nbins=30)
        xs = range(0, len(v))
        ys = v
        plt.plot(xs, ys, label='chiave_{}'.format(k))
    plt.minorticks_on()
    plt.legend()
    plt.margins(x=0)
    plt.show()
```

Comment: Adding your line give me correctly the legend but only one of the three line in the graph

Comment: I have edited the code. I am not sure what values you are getting and structure of your dict. with `plt.legend` you will get the your output with few tweaks.

Comment: i have the same code you have. (the list is a list of dictionaries with multiple values for each key). 
What I obtain are 3 graphics with the three lines but in each graphic the  legend has only one keyname appearing three times, the same for each color.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a possible solution:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(14,8)) 
plt.title('Grafico ripetizioni per linea')
plt.xlabel('numero caratteri')
plt.ylabel('ripetizioni per linea')
plt.minorticks_on()
plt.margins(x=0)
plt.locator_params(axis='y', nbins=15)    
plt.locator_params(axis='x', nbins=30)

for k,v in dd.items():
        xs = range(0, len(v))
        ys = v
        plt.plot(xs, ys, label=f'chiave_{k}') 
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```